# Building AOSP for my HTC Device

Tags: android, android-source, htc-android

So, I decided to do something about the AOSP ROM deficiency of my HTC device and build one of my own.

I have the kernel source archive from HTCDev, which as the kernel source .zip and a platform.zip file in it (which further has the 'development' and 'external' directories in it). This is unlike Sony's devices, which are already hosted on GitHub with the required configurations and a very helpful guide to building your own AOSP ROM. For HTC, I am not understanding what goes where.

I have followed the Sony guide to the point where I need to download around 10GB of source code, that unpacks into some 29GB of it.

So, here's my question.. Can anyone help me understand what goes where from the HTC source? Is the HTCDev source file enough to enable a vanilla AOSP build for the device?

I have searched the web like a madman but found absolutely nothing on how to build AOSP for HTC. All I get from people are XDA-U links that aren't too helpful to me because of my lack of understanding. Please help!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

A lot of work goes into building a custom ROM for a device. Many proprietary binaries, which you probably won't find in your source from HTC, need to be merged into the build as well as creating the correct configuration.

I suggest you look at [building CyanogenMod](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Doc:_Building_Basics) for your device first as they may have already done a lot of the leg work required for baselining new devices. After you get comfortable with Cyanogenmod builds, you should be able to start building AOSP for your device.

You will also be able to ask more specific questions in the correct forum on XDA once you get the basics down.

Comment: The proprietary binaries are in the vendor tree, right? I haven't got hold of that yet. I will try CM before diving into AOSP, though there isn't a CyanogenMod for my device yet. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @buggerman Any luck here? I'm also trying to build AOSP/Lollipop for an HTC M9. Starting with CM as well but looking for pointers on how to do this from AOSP instead.

Comment: @scorpiodawg nope. I ended up selling the device and switched to iPhone instead. If I ever use Android, it will only be a Nexus. Anything else is a waste of time..

Comment: Ha ouch! Well, I'm considering starting from scratch on a well-supported device first (Nexus, for instance) before trying anything else.