# Building AOSP for custom device

Tags: android, android-source, motorola

I'm new to the Android modding and I wonder how I build the AOSP without modifications for my own device (Motorola Moto G 2014).
I read already the Google guide but it only shows the way how to build the system for a Nexus device (I guess the AOSP source only contains the drivers for those devices).
So what do I need to prepare for building for my device? I saw that CyanogenMod has for each device they support two repositories, one with the kernel and one with stuff I don't know).
Is it possible to build the AOSP without any modifications at all?

Thanks for responses
*firefligher*

Comment: You'd need the kernel, a boot image, and a recovery image and maybe other stuff. I'm assuming that's what Cyanogen is giving you

Comment: You may want to look at http://www.xda-developers.com for your specific device as your question is more forum-like than Q&A

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building AOSP for my HTC Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407337/building-aosp-for-my-htc-device)

Answer (score 1):

AOSP will build without modification - but only for the Google Nexus devices and emulators.

Remember that Android is an entire operating system - not just some simple software that you can build for any platform. In particular, you will need a working kernel along with boot and hardware drivers to be able to build Android for a specific device.